# Passing DateTime[] to the view to deploy as a dropdown in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I had a look at this:

[ASP.NET MVC - How to pass an Array to the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405383/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-an-array-to-the-view)

and am struggeling with deploying my DateTime[] as a dropdownlist in the view, herewith my line but it is not correct:

```
<p style="color:Red"><%: Html.DropDownList("Choose a Sunday: ", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Sundays"], "--Select--")%>
</p>
```

In the controller i have:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  DateTime[] allSundaysInMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now);
  ViewData["Sundays"] = allSundaysInMonth;
  return View();
}
```

can someone help please?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you want to do is this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> allSundaysInMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now).Select(day => new SelectListItem() { Text = day.ToString(), Value = day.ToString() });
  ViewData["Sundays"] = allSundaysInMonth;
  return View();
}
```

That is depending on your display format. What I'm trying to point out is that `DateTime` and `SelectListItem` may not have an implicit cast, so you get a type mismatch at runtime.

Comment: yup I would like to keep my type in the controller as DateTime[] though and cast in the view rather?

Comment: sure, in that case:  `<p style="color:Red"><%: Html.DropDownList("Choose a Sunday: ", ((DateTime[])ViewData["Sundays"]).Select(day => new SelectListItem() { Text = day.ToString(), Value = day.ToString() }), "--Select--")%>
</p>`. Also consider Shyju's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever think (realize) dynamic magic variables like `ViewData`/ `ViewBag` is an evil and thinking about using strongly typed ViewModel for your view, you can do like this

create a `ViewModel` specific for your View (UI).

```
public class EventViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllSundays { set;get;}
  public string SelectedSunday { set;get;}
}
```

In your action method, set the value and send it to the view

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  var vm=new EventViewModel();
  vm.AllSundays = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now).
          Select(d => new SelectListItem() {
            Text = d.ToString(), Value = d.ToString() }).ToList();

  return View(vm);
}
```

Change your view like this

```
@model EventViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedSunday, Model.AllSundays, "--Select One--")
```

**ViewBag/ViewData is bad. It makes your code ugly. Stick to strongly typed.**

Answer (score 0):

You cast the list to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, but its a list of DateTimes. Casting the list to `IEnumerable<DateTime>` should fix it.

Or you might want to put list of `SelectListItem` on the ViewData instead!