# how can pass more than one query object to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i have an action named `PackageIndex` in which i am creating a list type view of package class ..in this view i use  layout in which i have to to display notification on navbar ...for that purpose i have to pass notification list to layout to display notification..my code is given below...

```
  public ActionResult PackageIndex()
        {
            //feedback counter
            int count = feedbackCounter();
            ViewData["FeedbackCount"] = count;
            int notificationcount = notificationCounter();
            ViewData["notificationcount"] = notificationcount;
            return View(db.packages.ToList());
        }
```

in this action i also have to passs (`db.notification.ToList()`)...to provide data to layout ..i can't understand how to solve this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - How to pass an Array to the view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405383/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-an-array-to-the-view)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model for this view, for example:

```
public class PackageIndexModel()
{
    public List<Package> Packages { get; set; }
    public int NotificationCount { get; set; }
    public int FeedbackCount { get; set; }
}
```

and you can return this

```
var obj = new PackageIndexModel() { Packages = db.packages.ToList(), NotificationCount = notificationCounter(), FeedbackCount = feedbackCounter() };
return View(obj);
```

Or you could just set that object on a TempData:

```
TempData["Notifications"] = obj;
```

And in your _Layout.cshtml:

```
@{
    if (TempData["Notifications"] != null)
    {
        foreach (var notification in ((PackageIndexModel)TempData["Notification"]).Packages)
        {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                    alert('@notification.Message');
                });
            </script>
        }

        TempData["Notifications"] = null;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I think the second example is cleaner, because on don't have to receive your notifications on every view you create.

Comment: if i follow second case then i also have to make 'packageIndexmodel' or this is essential for only case first .

Comment: No, you don't. You could pass a list of strings to your tempdata, and your foreach would be something like this: foreach (var notification in (List<string>)TempData["Notification"])

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<WebApplication5.Models.Feedback>

<table class="table">
   

@foreach (var item in (List<string>)TempData["Notification"]){
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b class="label label-primary"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)</b> <p>send feedback about</p><b class="label label-primary">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.subject)</b>
            <hr />
        </td>

    </tr>
    }

</table> `
item does not contain any email getting error...

Comment: Of course, you set a list of string and tried to access an email property.

Comment: If you're using a list os string in your tempdata, it just that string. If you set a list of Packages in your tempdata, you have all properties from that object.

Comment: i solved this but i gain i getting error...The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication5.Models.UserManager]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication5.Models.Feedback]'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115888/discussion-between-gnllucena-and-sajiii).