# Passing data from SQL to MVC Array System.String[] Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing a Stored Procedure into my Controller, which I then want to send to my View and log each entry of the Stored Procedure into a dropdown menu. My problem is that when I pass the data over to the dropdown menu, all I get is System.String[] instead of the actual value.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Dropdown()
{
    ViewData["ids"] = db.uspGetAllEventIds().ToArray();
    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Heatmap.Models.Event>
...
<body>
    <div>
        <select name="EventId">
            @for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {

                <option>@ViewData["ids"]</option>
            }
        </select>

    </div>
</body>
```

Right now I only have a simple `for` loop set to 6, but I want to iterate through my entire `ids` array (which should be filled with the values from `db.uspGetAllEventIds()` and enter them into my dropdown menu. How should I set my loop up to do this?

Comment: @Icarus I am passing the array from controller to view. I'm confused where you are getting lost. Maybe I can explain more?

Comment: if the viewdata is a list, should it not be acced via index `@ViewData["ids"][i]`?

Comment: @lloyd Yes that's what I thought too. I don't remember exactly why that didn't work (I haven't looked at it since last Wednesday) but it was either a compiler error or returning System.String[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a string array inside `ViewData` object, you need to cast `ViewData` into `string[]` with `as` operator (or simply a direct casting if you're sure not throwing exception) and later iterate the contents as shown in code below:

```
@model IEnumerable<Heatmap.Models.Event>
...
<body>
    <div>
        <select name="EventId">
            @{
                // a simple (string[])ViewData["ids"] also work here
                var ids = ViewData["ids"] as string[];
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
                {
                    <option>@ids[i]</option>
                }
             }
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Working example: [.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rjYowd)

NB: You can't access array elements using `ViewData["ids"][i]` inside `for` loop because `ViewData` is a dynamic dictionary which has `object` type, not `object[]`.

Tip: If you want to iterate through entire `ids` array, use `ids.Length` as upper limit value in `for` loop after casting `ViewData`.

Reference:

[ASP.NET MVC - How to pass an Array to the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405383/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-an-array-to-the-view)

[How to pass an array from Controller to View?](https://forums.asp.net/t/1705737.aspx?How%20to%20pass%20an%20array%20from%20Controller%20to%20View%20)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Sorry for the delayed response, I took an early weekend xD