# Calling multiple partial views into one controller for CMS system

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, contentful

I am trying to call multiple partial views into one controller. I have a carousel that will have at least 3 slides that will be managed by a CMS. I want to be able to do a partial view for each of those slide and call them all into the home controller with an array. I know that my view will need the foreach loop but do I need a separate model for each of those partial views or will one model work? I did look at this question and answers but I think its a little different than what I am looking for ([ASP.NET MVC - How to pass an Array to the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405383/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-an-array-to-the-view)) I've included the partial view first. The view, model and controller code. I apologize ahead of time the code is a mess. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    Partial View - @{
ViewData["Title"] = "_CorporateEvents";
}

<div>
@foreach (var image in Model)
{
    <img width="850" height="700">
    <img source src="@image.EventImages.File.Url" type="image"
         alt="Your browser does not support the image tag." />
}
```

```
       View--<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
         </div>
        <div class="item">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_CorporateEvents.cshtml");
        </div>




     Model---namespace MyLink.Models
     {
public class CorporateEvents
{
    [JsonProperty("eventImages")]
    public Asset EventImages { get; set; }
}
   }





   Controller ----public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        var qb = QueryBuilder<CorporateEvents>.New.ContentTypeIs("corporateEvents");
        var entries = await _client.GetEntriesAsync(qb);


          return View(entries);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in short, no you do not need a separate model for a partial view. You can simply pass a model to each partial like this:

`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_CorporateEvents.cshtml", modelGoesHere);`

However, a few things strikes me as odd in your example.

Your controller grabs a number of entries from contentful and each entry contains exactly one `Asset`. Are these supposed to be your items in the carousel?

If so I would create a view that looks like this:

`<div class="carousel-inner">
    @foreach(var slide in Model) {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_CorporateEvents.cshtml", slide);
    }
</div>`

and the partial view something like this:

`<div class="item">
    <img source src="@image.EventImages.File.Url" type="image"
         alt="Your browser does not support the image tag." />
</div>`

I'd also suggest using the `<contentful-image>` taghelper instead of an img tag to leverage the contentful image API. You could then replace your partial view by something like this:

`<div class="item">
    <contentful-image url="@image.EventImages.File.Url" width="850" height="700"
         alt="Your browser does not support the image tag." />
</div>`

Just add `@addTagHelper *, Contentful.AspNetCore` to your `_ViewImports` file.

You can read more about the contentful-image taghelper and what other options are available here: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/net/tutorials/aspnet-core/